# Type for JSON field on Type-GraphQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, apollo, prisma, typegraphql

I'm defining a custom input field on type-graphql of type JSON. We're using Prisma as well. I tried with Prisma.JsonValue, Prisma.JsonObject and JSON but I get this errors. any suggestion will be welcome
[image]

Comment: Please do not use images to convey code or errors. We need to be able to copy/paste code and errors when working on solutions. An image forces us to retype everything and, as a result, discourages people helping you. Also, images can't be scraped by search engines keeping your question from helping others when searching for solutions.

Comment: See "[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/128421)"
"[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812)"
"[I downvoted because an image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)"
"[I downvoted because an image of your exception isn't helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/)"
for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly use Prisma-generated models as type definitions in TypeGraphQL. You will need to create custom classes as [shown in the TypeGraphQL docs](https://typegraphql.com/docs/types-and-fields.html) (with `@ObjectType()`, `@InputType()` etc decorators).

There is a third party library for generating TypeGraphQL types from Prisma called [typegraphql-prisma](https://github.com/MichalLytek/typegraphql-prisma) which you could consider. However, in my opinion it's easier to define the classes manually.

Furthermore, I'm not sure what you mean by `JsonValue`. If you need to pass arbitrary JSON data, perhaps you could stringify your JSON object and pass it as a String?